# how could i get the data from specific metric from aws cloudwatch?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

```
    long offsetInMilliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60;

    GetMetricStatisticsRequest request1 = new GetMetricStatisticsRequest()
            .withStartTime(new Date(new Date().getTime() - offsetInMilliseconds))
            .withNamespace("AWS/DynamoDB")
            .withPeriod(60*60)
            .withDimensions(new Dimension().withName("TableName").withValue("INT_LOG_TABLE").withName("Operation").withValue("PutItem"))
            .withMetricName("SuccessfulRequestLatency")
            .withStatistics("Average")
            .withEndTime(new Date());


    GetMetricStatisticsResult getMetricStatisticsResult = cw.getMetricStatistics(request1);

    double avgRequestLatency = 0;
    List dataPoint = getMetricStatisticsResult.getDatapoints();
    for (Object aDataPoint : dataPoint){
        Datapoint dp = (Datapoint) aDataPoint;
        avgRequestLatency = dp.getAverage();

    }
```

i tried like this.

i cannot get in for loop

that's because "getMetricStatisticsResult" is

"Label: SuccessfulRequestLatency,Datapoints: []"

how can i get "DataPoints"??

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be many reasons why this doesn't return any datapoints.

Let's start with the code itself:

```
.withDimensions(new Dimension().withName("TableName").withValue("INT_LOG_TABLE").withName("Operation").withValue("PutItem"))
```

Here you are creating only one dimension and setting name and value twice, so the result is a Dimension with `name="Operation"` and `value="PutItem"`.

Try doing this instead:

```
.withDimensions(Arrays.asList(
    new Dimension().withName("TableName").withValue("INT_LOG_TABLE"),
    new Dimension().withName("Operation").withValue("PutItem")))
```

Answer (score 0):

A single dimension can set using single object. You have two dimension for which you need to create two object of dimensions.

Try the below code it works:

```
long offsetInMilliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60

Dimension dimension1 = new Dimension();
        dimension.setName("TableName");
        dimension.setValue("INT_LOG_TABLE");

Dimension dimension2 = new Dimension();
        dimension.setName("Operation");
        dimension.setValue("PutItem");
GetMetricStatisticsRequest request1 = new GetMetricStatisticsRequest()
        .withStartTime(new Date(new Date().getTime() - offsetInMilliseconds))
        .withNamespace("AWS/DynamoDB")
        .withPeriod(60*60)
        .withDimensions(dimension1, dimension2)
        .withMetricName("SuccessfulRequestLatency")
        .withStatistics("Average")
        .withEndTime(new Date());


GetMetricStatisticsResult getMetricStatisticsResult = cw.getMetricStatistics(request1);

double avgRequestLatency = 0;
List dataPoint = getMetricStatisticsResult.getDatapoints();
for (Object aDataPoint : dataPoint){
    Datapoint dp = (Datapoint) aDataPoint;
    avgRequestLatency = dp.getAverage();

}
```